# example for posting message to user wall after accepting my application but user is logged out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

Is it possible to post a comment in user's wall after he accepted my application?

I have registered my application, I have my `AppId`, `AppSecret`, suppose that the users logged in with his facebook account some time ago, and authorize my application with this permission `publish_stream`.

I want now a simple textbox, a button, and a checkbox with the option "send comment to facebook" and I want to post that comment to facebook after doing some stuff in my application. What should I need to do in the controller? Do I need to store something when the user allows my application for first time. I am using FB C# SDK and Asp.Net MVC but if you suggest something else I can use it, a code example will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to perform actions on behalf of the user when they're not actively logged in, ask for the `offline_access` permission, and also store the access token for the user (probably in a database).

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer, do you have any example using facebook-c#-sdk or anything else? I can't find the right methods

Comment: When the user is logged in, you can grab the access token from the `FacebookClient`'s `AccessToken` property and save it into the database. Afterward, when you want to post to their wall, grab the access token from the database, and pass it to the constructor for `FacebookClient` (I don't have much experience with the C# SDK, but this seems like the right place to do this).